# RxJS modeling if else control structures with Observables operators

Tags: rxjs

Is it possible to model if/else control structures via RxJS operators. As far as I understood we could use Observable.filter() to simulate an IF branch, but I am not sure if we simulate an ELSE branch via any of the Observable operator.

Comment: Did you read it http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/if.html or it http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/case.html?

Comment: @xgrommx, actually I am using your Rx book to learn RxJS. I've completely missed the `elseSource` parameter from the `if` operator. Thanks a lot the `Rx.Observable.if()` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are a couple operators that you could use to emulate this:

In order from most likely what you are asking for

[**partition**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/partition.md)

```
//Returns an array containing two Observables
//One whose elements pass the filter, and another whose elements don't

var items = observableSource.partition((x) => x % 2 == 0);

var evens = items[0];
var odds = items[1];

//Only even numbers
evens.subscribe();

//Only odd numbers
odds.subscribe();

// Using RxJS >= 6
const [evens, odds] = partition(observableSource, x => x % 2 == 0);

//Only even numbers
evens.subscribe();

//Only odd numbers
odds.subscribe();
```

[**groupBy**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupby.md)

```
//Uses a key selector and equality comparer to generate an Observable of GroupedObservables
observableSource.groupBy((value) => value % 2, (value) => value)
  .subscribe(groupedObservable => {
    groupedObservable.subscribe(groupedObservable.key ? oddObserver : evenObserver);
  });
```

[**if**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/if.md) *edit* renamed to [**iif**](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif) in v6

```
//Propagates one of the sources based on a particular condition
//!!Only one Observable will be subscribed to!!
Rx.Observable.if(() => value > 5, Rx.Observable.just(5), Rx.Observable.from([1,2, 3]))

// Using RxJS >= 6
iif(() => value > 5, of(5), from([1, 2, 3]))
```

[**case**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/case.md) (Only available in RxJS 4)

```
//Similar to `if` but it takes an object and only propagates based on key matching
//It takes an optional argument if none of the items match
//!!Only one Observable will be subscribed to!!
Rx.Observable.case(() => "blah",
{
  blah : //..Observable,
  foo : //..Another Observable,
  bar : //..Yet another
}, Rx.Observable.throw("Should have matched!"))
```

Comment: thanks for providing this comprehensive list of operators. I guess depending on use case I can use one of these operators to simulate `if/else`. For my particular example `Rx.Observable.if()` did the trick.

Comment: Tons more operators/details at the rxjs docs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md

Comment: Thanks for all the details. ```Rx.Observable.if()``` with ```elseSource``` did the trick.

Comment: Despite it being nowhere to be found in the docs, Observable.if is in fact available in RxJs 5.

Comment: @paulpdaniels how does the groupby works if we're using hot observable ?

Comment: @John Same as any hot Observable. If you aren't subscribed then nothing, the events are just lost. If you are then you'll receive the events. Also note that each `GroupedObservable` that is passed out of `groupBy` is itself a hot `Observable`