# Is there an more ideomatic way to split a stream by some predicate?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a stream of events, which I want to split into multiple streams, based on some property the event may have. Something like the following

```
let streams = new rx.Subject()
let stream = new rx.Subject()
input.subscribe((x) => {
  stream.onNext(x)
  if (!x.splitHere) return
  streams.onNext(stream)
  stream = new rx.Subject()
})
```

**EDIT**
Thank you for the hints about `partition` and `if`. While they do split one stream into multiple, they only provide two result streams.

**Clarification**
What I need to do is to cut one stream into a variable number of streams, and the incision point be defined by the predicate.

```
# partition
in    a---b---a---a---b--------b----a---
out1  a-------a---a-----------------a---
out2  ----b-----------b--------b--------

# what I need is to cut after every X
in      a-b-c-X-d-e-f-g-h-X-i-X-j-k-l-m-n-
out v   a-b-c-X
    v          -d-e-f-g-h-X
    v                      -i-X
    v                          -j-k-l-m-n-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window` does this.

```
const streams = input
  .filter(x => x !== 'X')
  .window(input.filter(x => x === 'X'));
```

Using `partition` and array destructuring you can get something that (in my opinion) reads very nicely:

```
const [ incisions, items ] = input.partition(x => x === 'X');
const streams = items.window(incisions);
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an operator called `partition`:

```
const source$ = Rx.Observable.from([{ a: 'value' }, { b: 'value' }]);
const [hasA$, doesNotHaveA$] = source$.partition(x => Boolean(x.a));
```

Typically if you want to derive streams that satisfy some criteria/predicate, the best way to do so is to use the `filter` operator:

```
const hasA$ = source$.filter(x => Boolean(x.a));
const satisfiesOtherCriteria$ = source$.filter(somePredicate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suposing you are referring to splitting (i.e. you get several streams out of one), you have a very nice and thorough treatment of that question here : [RxJS modeling if else control structures with Observables operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594357/rxjs-modeling-if-else-control-structures-with-observables-operators/32601397#32601397)

Here is the summary :

There are a couple operators that you could use to emulate this:

In order from most likely what you are asking for :

- [partition](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/partition.md)
- [groupBy](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupby.md)
- [if](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/if.md)
- [case](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/case.md)

Code examples are provided in the link.

If you are referring to filtering (getting one stream out of one stream but skipping some values), then the `filter` operator is your best bet. There are also other operators which do some kind of filtering, such as `distinct`, or `distinctUntilChanged`, `skip` etc.