# How to split a stream with some predicate

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065735/is-there-an-more-ideomatic-way-to-split-a-stream-by-some-predicate) it is written how to split a stream into many ones by some border mark. It is accomplished with `.window` and `.filter`.

```
in      a-b-c-X-d-e-f-g-h-X-i-X-j-k-l-m-n-
out v   a-b-c-X
    v          -d-e-f-g-h-X
    v                      -i-X
    v                          -j-k-l-m-n-
```

But how to split a stream *before* a border mark? Like this:

```
in      a-b-c-X-d-e-f-g-h-X-i-X-j-k-l-m-n-
out v   a-b-c
    v         X-d-e-f-g-h
    v                     X-i
    v                         X-j-k-l-m-n-
```

Comment: add the border mark back with `startWith` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you refer to doesn't actually include the markers in any of the output streams, only the items that come between them. As suggested by user3743222 in the comments, if you wanted them in the output streams, you could simply put them back in. Something like this:

```
const marker = 'X';
const [ incisions, items ] = input.partition(x => x === marker);
const streams = items.window(incisions);
const first = streams.take(1);
const rest = streams.skip(1);
const whatYouWant = first.concat(rest.map(x => Rx.Observable.just(marker).concat(x)));
```

However, one of the less-used overloads of `window` is actually capable of doing this directly:

```
const closing = input.filter(x => x === 'X').share();
const opening = Rx.Observable.just(null).concat(closing);
const streams = input.window(opening, () => closing);
```

Comment: It's in offical documentation now: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/window.md

Comment: Right you are; I'll remove that from my answer.