# How to do if/else in ngrx/effects?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am using ngrx/effects. I want to dispatch different actions based on a `foo` state in the store.

This is how I am doing now:

```
 @Effect() foo1$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(Actions.FOO)
    .filter(obj => !obj.state.product.foo)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .map(x => ({ type: Actions.BAR1, payload: { x }}));

  @Effect() foo2$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(Actions.FOO)
    .filter(obj => obj.state.product.foo)
    .map<string>(toPayload)
    .map(x => ({ type: Actions.BAR2, payload: { x }}));
```

Is there a way to use RxJS 5 operators like `partition`, `groupBy`, `if`, `case` in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594357/rxjs-modeling-if-else-control-structures-with-observables-operators)? I cannot use it correctly now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having 2 separate effect sources are fine. Otherwise make it simple:

```
@Effect() foo$ = this.updates$
    .whenAction(Actions.FOO)
    .map(({action, state}) => {
        if (state.product.foo) {
            return { type: Actions.CHAT_GET_MESSAGES2, payload: { action.payload }};
        } else {
            return { type: Actions.CHAT_GET_MESSAGES, payload: { action.payload }};
        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't help if you need to do more through the rxjs pipeline after one of the conditions.