# How can I branch a ngrx effects chain based on return type of the data?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

```
  @Effect()
  results$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchActions.Action_X)
    .map(Operation_OP)
    .do(conole.log);//<=payload of type X
    .map(....)

  @Effect()
  results$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchActions.Action_X)
    .map(Operation_OP)
    .do(conole.log);//<=payload of type Y
    .map(....)
```

I need conditionally branch to do differnent operations, based on the return value of some operaton but I need to store the result in the same results$ (The above code would through error as results$ is declared twice, please suggest correct way to achieve this)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299386/how-to-do-if-else-in-ngrx-effects) doesn't answer my question as it branches based on Action, my case its the same action Action_X to intiate the chain but successive steps will need to be different based on twhat is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
@Effect()
    results$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchActions.Action_X)
    .map(action => {
        result = operation();
        if (result === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        } 
    }
);
```