# RxJS 5 task queue, continue if a task fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, rxjs5, reactive-extensions-js

Imagine that we have an HTML page that fires AJAX requests. We want to make sure that AJAX requests are executed in order. The next AJAX request won't be fired until the previous one completes or errors.

I have tried to model this via a task queue using RxJS `concatMap`. Each AJAX request is modeled as an `Observable`. Everything is working great if AJAX request completes successfully, however if it errors, then the next task in the queue is not executed.

Here is an example, that uses `setTimeout()` to simulate long running async tasks:

```
  function identity(observable) {
    return observable;
  }

  function createTaskQueue() {
    var subject= new Rx.Subject();

    subject
    .concatMap(identity)
    .onErrorResumeNext(Rx.Observable.of('error'))
    .subscribe(function(data) {
      console.log('onNext', data);
    }, 
    function(error) {
      console.log('onError', error);
    });

    return {
      addTask: function(task) {
        subject.next(task);
      }
    }
  }

  function createTask(data, delay) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(obs) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        obs.next(data);
        obs.complete();
      }, delay);
    });
  }

  function createErrorTask(data, delay) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(obs) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        obs.error('Error: ' + data);
        obs.complete();
      }, delay);
    });
  }

  var taskQueue = createTaskQueue();

  taskQueue.addTask(createTask(11, 500))
  taskQueue.addTask(createTask(22, 200));
  taskQueue.addTask(createErrorTask(33, 1000));
  taskQueue.addTask(createTask(44, 300));
  taskQueue.addTask(createErrorTask(55, 300));
  taskQueue.addTask(createTask(66, 300));
```

Here is an executable example: https://jsfiddle.net/artur_ciocanu/s6ftxwnf/.

When I run this code the following is printed to the console:

`onNext 11
onNext 22
onNext error`

Which is expected, but I wonder why the other tasks like 44, 55, etc are not executed.

I am pretty sure I am doing something stupid with `onErrorResumeNext()` or may be the whole approach is totally wrong.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `onErrorResumeNext`,

> Continues an observable sequence that is terminated normally or by an
>   exception with the next observable sequence or Promise.

What that means is that when your source observable will encounter an error, it will switch to whatever you passed to `onErrorResumeNext`. What happens here is that `Rx.of(...)` terminates immediately after emitting its value. Hence the behavior you observe.

So in short, you don't want `onErrorResumeNext` here.

You could instead `.catch(...)` the stream which could emit an error. So, something like :

```
subject
    .concatMap(obs => obs.catch(Rx.Observable.of('error')))
    .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Nice to hear. Then you should take the time to ACCEPT an answer if it worked for you, and UPVOTE it if it was useful. That is valid for this answer but also for this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594357/rxjs-modeling-if-else-control-structures-with-observables-operators, and this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914801/javascript-new-date-gettime-with-timezone-offset-calculations-returns-9-999

Answer (score 0):

the idea of an error in observables is the same as in regular function. Meaning if you throw an error in a regular function - function will not return anything. The same is with observables - if observable emits an error that means stream is completed and no more values is coming. So yes it is fundamentally wrong.

The better (right) approach would be to to have a stream of responses where next value can be either successful response or and error response. And if you need to separate them you can split responses stream into two successful/error responses later on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. I was thinking that this is a bad idea, but I wanted to know what the community has to say.